# Django REST: Passing extra fields from connected models

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need to add additional fields that are not part of my model to the json response. Is this possible? The models are connected using multiple tables, but do not have a direct connection.

models.py

```
class Message(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=False)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    conversation = models.ForeignKey(Conversation)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    conversation = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='conversation.id')
    sender = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='sender.id')
    # task = TaskSerializer(source='conversation__task_worker__task.id')
    # This commented code above is not working, but this is what I need.
    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = '__all__'
```

So what I need, is to pass the value of task, which can be found by going back a few tables. E.g. if the current model is Message, I need to:
Message -> Conversation -> Task_worker -> Task (Get this)

My current json response is:

```
{
    "count": 2,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "conversation": 1,
            "sender": 2,
            "body": "Hello There",
            "timestamp": "2018-01-31T17:48:19.680113Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "conversation": 1,
            "sender": 2,
            "body": "Can you do the task",
            "timestamp": "2018-02-01T09:39:24.797218Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

***Ideally***, I would like the following response:

```
{
    "count": 2,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "conversation": 1,
    "task": 5,
    "any_extra_fields_key": 'value',
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "sender": 2,
            "body": "Hello There",
            "timestamp": "2018-01-31T17:48:19.680113Z"
        },
    ]
}
```

The response is after (list view): `GET /api/conversations/<conversation-id>/messages/`

---

EDIT: added views.py

```
class MessageList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = MessageSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        conversation = Conversation.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['conv_id'])
        queryset = Message.objects.filter(conversation=conversation)
        return queryset

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        conversation = Conversation.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['conv_id'])
        serializer.save(sender=self.request.user, conversation=conversation)
```

---

EDIT 2:

```
class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sender = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='sender.id')
    children_list = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_children')

    def get_children(self, obj):
        serializer = TaskSerializer(source='conversation__task_worker__task', many=True)
        return serializer.data

    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ['children_list','sender','conversation','timestamp']
```

outputs:

```
{
    "count": 2,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "children_list": [],
            "sender": 2,
            "conversation": 1,
            "timestamp": "2018-01-31T17:48:19.680113Z"
        },
        {
            "children_list": [],
            "sender": 2,
            "conversation": 1,
            "timestamp": "2018-02-01T09:39:24.797218Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

First of all, children list is empty, but it should be the task, and also it's still inside the `'results'` key, creating a lot of duplication, since the `children_list` is the same task.

Answer (score 0):

`SerializerMethodField` is what I needed to get me the data that I want. However, the structure is still a problem

```
class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
sender = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='sender.id')
task_id = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

def get_task_id(self, obj):
    task = Task.objects.filter(task_worker__conversation__message=obj)[0]
    return task.id


class Meta:
    model = Message
    fields = ['task_id','sender','conversation','timestamp']
```